# SQL Server query to pull a combination values from the table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table T as below.

I would like to pick a client who has their status `Processed, InProgress` combination.

Please could you help, how can I do it?

**Table**

```
ClientId    ClientName  Status
1           A           Processed
1           A           Processed
2           b           InProgress
2           b           Processed
3           c           Processed
3           c           Processed
4           d           InProgress
4           d           Processed
5           e           InProgress
5           e           Processed
```

**Result should be**

```
ClientId    ClientName  Status
2           b           InProgress
2           b           Processed
4           d           InProgress
4           d           Processed
5           e           InProgress
5           e           Processed
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT * FROM T 
WHERE 
    clientId IN 
    (
        SELECT T1.clientId 
        FROM 
            T t1 JOIN T t2 
            ON t1.clientId = t2.clientId 
        WHERE 
            (t1.status = 'Processed' AND t2.status = 'InProgress') OR 
            (t2.status = 'Processed' AND t1.status = 'InProgress')
    )
```

Comment: @OverflowUser, oops, blunder! corrected the SQL (i think I should go to sleep)

Comment: @Got the results as expected, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right I would do this to get the result

```
select ClientId, ClientName, Status From Table T
where Status IN ('Processed', 'InProgress')
```

Comment: If I put this condition by dafaul, client 1 and 3 will be in the result, So I don't want to see the client 1,3.